# Deleting a string from another string and producing all the possible outcomes

Tags: python, algorithm, search, iteration

I can't seem to see my logical error and why it isn't iterating through all possible solutions, can anyone see my error?  Or am I approaching the problem completely backwards and there is a much better approach?

For example, if you are given `abcabcb` and told to remove `ab`, your possible outcomes would be `cabcb, bcacb, bcabc, abccb, abcbc` EDIT in this question the string you are removing has to remain in order, so **ab is not the same as ba**

```
given = abcabcb  
removed = ab  

XXcabcb  
XbcaXcb  
XbcabcX  
abcXXcb  
abcXbcX
```

My current code would discover the first answer twice, second answer, third answer, first answer again, and then discover the fourth twice and stop.

the print outputs,
    `[0, 1, 'cabcb']
    [0, 4, 'bcacb']
    [0, 4, 'bcacb']
    [0, 4, 'bcacb']
    [0, 6, 'bcabc']
    [0, 6, 'bcabc']
    [0, 1, 'cabcb']
    [3, 4, 'abccb']
    [3, 4, 'abccb']
    [3, 4, 'abccb']`

and the result is `['cabcb', 'cabcb', 'bcacb', 'bcacb', 'bcacb', 'bcabc', 'bcabc', 'cabcb', 'abccb', 'abccb', 'abccb']`

python code:

```
def hiddenMessage(given, remove):
    alist = []
    temp = []
    temp = oneHiddenMessage(given, remove)
    alist.append(temp[len(temp)-1])
    count = 0

    for i in range(len(remove)-1,-1,-1):
        for j in range(temp[i], len(given)):
            temp = oneHiddenMessagerec(given, remove, i, j)
            if temp == False:
                return alist
            alist.append(temp[len(temp)-1])
            print temp

def oneHiddenMessage(given, remove):
    message = ""
    index = 0
    counterR = 0 #what element in remove you are looking at
    returned = []
    for counterG in range(len(given)): #searches entire given word
        if counterR<len(remove): #makes sure hasn't gone beyond the elements of the string
            if given[counterG]==remove[counterR]: #if the character at position counterG of given is == as char at position counter R of remove skip over 
                counterR+=1 #increment counterR
                returned.append(counterG) #tracks the location of each char in removed relative to given
            else:
                message+=given[counterG] #if they aren't == add char to message
        else:
            message+=given[counterG] #if out of char from remove, throw rest of char onto message
    if len(message)!=(len(given)-len(remove)):
        return False #if not the expected size then not possible and throws false
    returned.append(message)
    return returned #returns locations of the removed char in respects to given and also the message


def oneHiddenMessagerec(given, remove, beingmoved, location):
    message = ""
    index = 0
    counterR = 0
    returned = []
    for counterG in range(len(given)):
        if counterR<len(remove):
            if given[counterG]==remove[counterR] and not (beingmoved==counterR and location>counterG): #checks whether they are the same element and not the same as the previous attempt
                counterR+=1
                returned.append(counterG)
            else:
                message+=given[counterG]

        else:
            message+=given[counterG]
    if len(message)!=(len(given)-len(remove)):
        return False

    returned.append(message)
    return returned
```

Comment: Good for you ;) And your question is *"I give up. Can you finish the job?"*

Comment: so whats your question?

Comment: Please explain your algorithm.

Comment: @DSM, probably `ab` does not mean `ba`.

Comment: @vish4071: ah, that makes sense.  So we have to remove letters in the same order as in `remove`.

Comment: @DSM so sorry about that, I'm new to the website and kept on editing so it would make more sense, but had that typo.  Thank you for catching that! The letters do have to be in correct order, but can be seperated.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 I added comments, if it still doesn't make sense, please let me know thanks

Comment: @RNar can't believe I forgot to add that, is there a better way to approach this problem, or am I going about it in the right direction, but have glaring errors I'm blind to?

Comment: @zvone I haven't given up!! I'm just completely lost and would love a kick in the head, nudge in the right direction, or a good samaritan haha ;)

Comment: "The letters do have to be in correct order, but can be separated."  --- That's an important part of your question, but it will get lost down here in the comments.  Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: There are 3 functions in your code and it is not clear to me what any of them is supposed to do. Anyway, it looks like there is to much code there to be right ;) Your algorithm should 1. find all `a`s in `abcabcb`; 2. for each `a` look for `b`s in the remaining data; 3. return indexes; 4. generate strings with removed indexes

Comment: @kevinJ.Chase just added to the question, thanks

Comment: @zvone ok, in this example, it would create two lists from the given `bcabcb` and `bcb` where `a` = 0 and `3` then go through and find the `b`s contained?  would this be best done recursively?  and I'll admit this is far from my pretties code... really really far ;)

Comment: @NickM Yes, I would try to get from `([], 'abcabcb', 'ab')` to `([0], 'bcabcb', 'b')` and `([3], 'bcb', 'b')`, and then to `([0,1],'',''), ([0,4],'',''), ([0,6],'',''), ([3,4],'',''), ([3,6],'','')` (and continue recursively because 'ab' could be longer)

Comment: @vzone You are an amazing person!! I'm going to try implementing that now, I'll post again the results.  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems too complicated and long to me. But I suggest another approach. You can find all the occurrences of the second string characters in first string. in your example this would result in an array like this: `[[0, 3], [1, 4, 6]]` then you should remove all the pairs such that first element is smaller than second element `[0,1],[0,4],[0,6],[3,4],[3,6]`. And this can be done with the help of a recursive function, choose one element from the first list then go to next list and choose an element bigger than the element of the previous list and so on.

```
0
.1
.4
.6
3
.1 # not good because 1<3
.4
.6
```

You can generalize this method like this:

```
first_string = "abcabcb"
second_string = "ab"
array = []
for c in second_string:
    arr = []
    for i,c2 in enumerate(first_string):
        if c2==c:
            arr.append(i)
    array.append(arr)
print array
def func(index,pre,s):
    if index == len(array):
        print s+first_string[pre+1:]
        return
    string = s
    p = 0
    while array[index][p]<pre:
        p+=1
        if p>=len(array[index]):
            return
    for i,c in enumerate(first_string):
        if p >=len(array[index]):
            return
        if i<=pre:
            continue
        if i == array[index][p]:
            func(index+1,i,string[:])
            string += c
            p+=1
        else:
            string += c
func(0,-1,"")
```

Output:

```
cabcb
bcacb
bcabc
abccb
abcbc
```

What is `func(0,-1,"")`? It says that we have to remove `second_string[0]` or `a` in this case which its index is more than `-1` and our string so far is `""`. Then as `first_string[0]='a'` we ignore it and call `func(1,0,"")` because we have removed `a` and we want to remove `second_string[1]` which its index > 0 and our current string is `""` as we didn't add `a`. Similarly the we remove next `b` and call `func(2,1,"")` it means we have removed the first two characters in the `second_string` and we should remove the next character, because there is no other character in `second_string` we add all the remaining characters in `first_string` to our `current_string` and print it. After that we go back one step in `func(1,0,"")` and try to find the next `b (second_string[1])` as the next `b` appears at index `4` we add `first_string[1,2,3]` to our `current_string` and call `func(2,4,'bca')` ... this routine continues until we find all the possible strings.

Comment: What are the parameters of func? I'm having a little trouble following the code...

Comment: ignore me, riddle it out :)

Comment: If you couldn't understand, try to write it by yourself step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Another Pythonic solution is to create the array of the occurrences of the second string characters in first string and by using `itertools.product` create all the increasing combinations and remove them from first string:

```
first_string = "abcabcb"
second_string = "ab"
array = []
for c in second_string:
    arr = []
    for i,c2 in enumerate(first_string):
        if c2==c:
            arr.append(i)
    array.append(arr)
from itertools import product
f = lambda x: all( [x[i-1]<x[i] for i in range(1,len(x))])
combs = list(filter(f,product(*array)))     
for item in combs:
    string = ""
    for i in range(len(first_string)):
        if i not in item:
            string += first_string[i]
    print string
```